# Nested custom components javafx - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx

So I know there are already many posts about similar issues but this one is a little strange and because I've already spent 5 hrs on this issue I'm turning to my last resort.

All I'm trying to do is create 2 custom components and put 1 of them inside the other from the fxml file. It should be really straight forward and I've done it before with other types of components but for some reason now it doesn't like it. Take a look,
**SecondaryInterface.kt**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane
import java.io.IOException

class SecondaryInterface : GridPane() {

    @FXML private lateinit var label: Label

    init {

        println("From SecondaryInterface: ")
        println("\t" + MainInterface::class.java)
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("main_interface.fxml"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("SecondaryInterface.kt"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("secondary_interface.fxml"))

        val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader(javaClass.getResource("secondary_interface.fxml"))
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this)
        fxmlLoader.setController(this)
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load<Any>()
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(exception)
        }
    }

}
```

**secondary_interface.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <Label fx:id="label" text="This is the secondary interface"></Label>

</fx:root>
```

Secondary interface is the nested component. Anything look off? Next,
**MainInterface.kt**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane
import java.io.IOException

class MainInterface : GridPane() {

    @FXML private lateinit var secondInterface: SecondaryInterface

    init {
        println("From MainInterface: ")
        println("\t" + MainInterface::class.java)
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("main_interface.fxml"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("SecondaryInterface.kt"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("secondary_interface.fxml"))

        val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader(javaClass.getResource("main_interface.fxml"))
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this)
        fxmlLoader.setController(this)
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load<Any>()
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

**main_interface.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import SecondaryInterface?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <Label text="This is primary interface"></Label>
    <SecondaryInterface fx:id="secondInterface"></SecondaryInterface>

</fx:root>
```

**Output/Error StackTrace**

```
From MyApplication: 
    class MainInterface
    file:/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/main_interface.fxml
    null
    file:/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/secondary_interface.fxml
From MainInterface: 
    class MainInterface
    file:/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/main_interface.fxml
    null
    file:/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/secondary_interface.fxml
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/main_interface.fxml

    at MainInterface.<init>(MainInterface.kt:24)
    at MyApplication.start(MyApplication.kt:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/Programming/Tests/NestedCustomComponents/out/production/NestedCustomComponents/main_interface.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at MainInterface.<init>(MainInterface.kt:22)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2914)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've analyzed this for too long and couldn't get anything useful out of it-_-
Here's what I've tried so far:

- Double-checking naming conventions (package names lowercase and class names start with uppercase)
- Re-building project several times
- Making sure I have proper imports
- Printing debug text like classpaths as seen in code and output to check if the required files can are noticeable (why can't it find my .kt files but it can find my .fxml files?)
- Specifying the fx:controller in the .fxml files
- Using `internal constructor()` (after class name)
- Declaring classes as `open`
- Adding VM arguments

```
    --module-path
    C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
    --add-modules
    javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

This was from a bigger project I'm working on. I stripped everything down to simplify the problem. 
Here are the other classes you need in case you want to try it for yourself,

**Main.kt**

```
import javafx.application.Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(MyApplication::class.java)
}
```

**MyApplication.kt**

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane
import javafx.stage.Stage
import MainInterface //Not imported because in same package

class MyApplication : Application() {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) { launch(*args) }

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {

        val mainScene = Scene(Pane(), 475.0, 425.0)
        ScreenController.stage = primaryStage
        ScreenController.scene = mainScene
        ScreenController.bindSceneWithStage()

        println("From MyApplication: ")
        println("\t" + MainInterface::class.java)
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("main_interface.fxml"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("/SecondaryInterface.kt"))
        println("\t" + javaClass.getResource("secondary_interface.fxml"))

        ScreenController.addScene("mainInterface", MainInterface()) //Crashes here

        ScreenController.stage!!.show()
        ScreenController.activateScene("mainInterface")
    }
}
```

**ScreenController.kt**

```
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane
import javafx.stage.Stage
import java.util.*

object ScreenController {

    var stage: Stage? = null
    var scene: Scene? = null
    private val mapOfCustomPanes = mutableMapOf<String, Pane>()

    fun bindSceneWithStage() {
        stage!!.scene = scene!!
    }

    fun addScene(name: String, pane: Pane) {
        mapOfCustomPanes[name] = pane
    }

    fun removeScene(name: String?) {
        mapOfCustomPanes.remove(name)
    }

    fun activateScene(name: String?) {
        scene!!.root = mapOfCustomPanes[name]
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm seriously at a loss with this. Thanks

Comment: Are your classes and FXML resources in a named package, or just in the default package? I'm not sure how the `FXMLLoader` handles instantiation of classes in the default package: arguably it should be able to do this, but IDK whether or not it actually can. It's not really good practice to use a default package anyway.

Comment: @James_D Yea everything's under the default `src` package. I'll try to separate the fxml files in their own package and the .kt classes in another under the src package and see if that works.

Comment: `src` isn't a package (it's a source folder, and isn't part of the build that's created for running the project). The "default" package is unnamed, and I'm guessing not having a package name is confusing the `FXMLLoader` `?import` directive. You don't necessarily need separate packages for the FXML and classes, but my guess is that you need any classes referenced by the FXML to be in a named package.

Comment: @James_D I put everything under a package in src and it works! Thank you so much, I never would have thought to try that.

Comment: @James_D I'll need to do some reading on proper project structure. Thanks for the insight